# User Motion Detection App keeps on crashing

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, motion-detection, activity-recognition

I have been working on this app.
It just won't execute.
Crashes everytime.Please help.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.androidrecipes.usermotionactivity"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name="com.androidrecipes.usermotionactivity.UserMotionService" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

UserMotionService.java

```
   package com.androidrecipes.usermotionactivity;


import com.google.android.gms.location.ActivityRecognitionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.location.DetectedActivity;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;

public class UserMotionService extends IntentService {
    private static final String TAG = "UserMotionService";

    /*
     * Callback interface for detected activity type changes
     */
    public interface OnActivityChangedListener{
        public void onUserActivityChanged(int bestChoice, int bestConfidence,
                ActivityRecognitionResult newActivity);
    }

    /* Last detected activity type */
    private DetectedActivity mLastKnownActivity;
    /*
     * Marshals requests from the background thread so the callbacks
     * can be made on the main (UI) thread.
     */
    private CallbackHandler mHandler;
    private static class CallbackHandler extends Handler {
        /* Callback for activity changes */
        private OnActivityChangedListener mCallback;

        public void setCallback(OnActivityChangedListener callback) {
            mCallback = callback;
        }

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            if (mCallback != null) {
                //Read payload data out of the message and fire callback
                ActivityRecognitionResult newActivity = (ActivityRecognitionResult) msg.obj;
                mCallback.onUserActivityChanged(msg.arg1, msg.arg2, newActivity);
            }
        }
    }

    public UserMotionService() {
        //String is used to name the background thread created
        super("UserMotionService");
        mHandler = new CallbackHandler();
    }

    public void setOnActivityChangedListener(OnActivityChangedListener listener) {
        mHandler.setCallback(listener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.w(TAG, "Service is stopping...");
    }

    /*
     * Incoming action events from the framework will come
     * in here.  This is called on a background thread, so
     * we can do long processing here if we wish.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (ActivityRecognitionResult.hasResult(intent)) {
            //Extract the result from the Intent
            ActivityRecognitionResult result =
                    ActivityRecognitionResult.extractResult(intent);
            DetectedActivity activity = result.getMostProbableActivity();
            Log.v(TAG, "New User Activity Event");

            //If the highest probability is UNKNOWN, but the confidence is low,
            // check if another exists and select it instead
            if (activity.getType() == DetectedActivity.UNKNOWN
                    && activity.getConfidence() < 60
                    && result.getProbableActivities().size() > 1) {
                //Select the next probable element
                activity = result.getProbableActivities().get(1);
            }

            //On a change in activity, alert the callback
            if (mLastKnownActivity == null
                    || mLastKnownActivity.getType() != activity.getType()
                    || mLastKnownActivity.getConfidence() != activity.getConfidence()) {
                //Pass the results to the main thread inside a Message
                Message msg = Message.obtain(null,
                        0,                         //what
                        activity.getType(),        //arg1
                        activity.getConfidence(),  //arg2
                        result);
                mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
            }
            mLastKnownActivity = activity;
        }
    }

    /*
     * This is called when the Activity wants to bind to the
     * service.  We have to provide a wrapper around this instance
     * to pass it back.
     */
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    /*
     * This is a simple wrapper that we can pass to the Activity
     * to allow it direct access to this service.
     */
    private LocalBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        public UserMotionService getService() {
            return UserMotionService.this;
        }
    }

    /*
     * Utility to get a good display name for each state
     */
    public static String getActivityName(DetectedActivity activity) {
        switch(activity.getType()) {
            case DetectedActivity.IN_VEHICLE:
                return "Driving";
            case DetectedActivity.ON_BICYCLE:
                return "Biking";
            case DetectedActivity.ON_FOOT:
                return "Walking";
            case DetectedActivity.STILL:
                return "Not Moving";
            case DetectedActivity.TILTING:
                return "Tilting";
            case DetectedActivity.UNKNOWN:
            default:
                return "No Clue";
        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
  package com.androidrecipes.usermotionactivity;

import com.androidrecipes.usermotionactivity.UserMotionService.LocalBinder;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.location.ActivityRecognitionClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.ActivityRecognitionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.location.DetectedActivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
        ServiceConnection,
        UserMotionService.OnActivityChangedListener,
        GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
    private static final String TAG = "UserActivity";

    private Intent mServiceIntent;
    private PendingIntent mCallbackIntent;
    private UserMotionService mService;

    private ActivityRecognitionClient mRecognitionClient;
    //Custom list adapter to display our results
    private ActivityAdapter mListAdapter;

    private View mBlockingView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mBlockingView = findViewById(R.id.blocker);

        //Construct a simple list adapter that will display all the
        // incoming activity change events from the service.
        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        mListAdapter = new ActivityAdapter(this);
        list.setAdapter(mListAdapter);

        //When the list is clicked, display all the probable activities
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                showDetails(mListAdapter.getItem(position));
            }
        });

        //Check if Google Play Services is up to date.
        switch (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this)) {
            case ConnectionResult.SUCCESS:
                //Do nothing, move on
                break;
            case ConnectionResult.SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED:
                Toast.makeText(this,
                        "Activity service requires an update, please open Google Play.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
                return;
            default:
                Toast.makeText(this,
                        "Activity service is not available on this device.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
                return;
        }
        //Create a client instance for talking to Google Services
        mRecognitionClient = new ActivityRecognitionClient(this, this, this);
        //Create an Intent to bind to the service
        mServiceIntent = new Intent(this, UserMotionService.class);
        //Create a PendingIntent that Google Services will use for callbacks
        mCallbackIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,
                mServiceIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        //Connect to Google Services and our Service
        mRecognitionClient.connect();
        bindService(mServiceIntent, this, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        //Disconnect from all services
        mRecognitionClient.removeActivityUpdates(mCallbackIntent);
        mRecognitionClient.disconnect();

        disconnectService();
        unbindService(this);
    }

    /** ServiceConnection Methods */

    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        //Attach ourselves to our Service as a callback for events
        mService = ((LocalBinder) service).getService();
        mService.setOnActivityChangedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        disconnectService();
    }

    private void disconnectService() {
        if (mService != null) {
            mService.setOnActivityChangedListener(null);
        }
        mService = null;
    }

    /** Google Services Connection Callbacks */

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        //We must wait until the services are connected
        // to request any updates.
        mRecognitionClient.requestActivityUpdates(5000, mCallbackIntent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected() {
        Log.w(TAG, "Google Services Disconnected");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Google Services Connection Failure");
    }

    /** OnActivityChangedListener Methods */

    @Override
    public void onUserActivityChanged(int bestChoice, int bestConfidence,
            ActivityRecognitionResult newActivity) {
        //Add latest event to the list
        mListAdapter.add(newActivity);
        mListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        //Determine user action based on our custom algorithm
        switch (bestChoice) {
            case DetectedActivity.IN_VEHICLE:
            case DetectedActivity.ON_BICYCLE:
                mBlockingView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;
            case DetectedActivity.ON_FOOT:
            case DetectedActivity.STILL:
                mBlockingView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                break;
            default:
                //Ignore other states
                break;
        }
    }

    /*
     * Utility that builds a simple Toast with all the probable
     * activity choices with their confidence values
     */
    private void showDetails(ActivityRecognitionResult activity) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("Details:");
        for(DetectedActivity element : activity.getProbableActivities()) {
            sb.append("\n"+UserMotionService.getActivityName(element)
                    + ", " + element.getConfidence() + "% sure");
        }

        Toast.makeText(this, sb.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    /*
     * ListAdapter to display each activity result we receive from the service
     */
    private static class ActivityAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ActivityRecognitionResult> {

        public ActivityAdapter(Context context) {
            super(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext())
                        .inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false);
            }
            //Display the most probable activity with its confidence in the list
            TextView tv = (TextView) convertView;
            ActivityRecognitionResult result = getItem(position);
            DetectedActivity newActivity = result.getMostProbableActivity();
            String entry = DateFormat.format("hh:mm:ss", result.getTime())
                    + ": " + UserMotionService.getActivityName(newActivity) + ", "
                    + newActivity.getConfidence() + "% confidence";
            tv.setText(entry);

            return convertView;
        }
    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
  09-02 10:29:16.635: D/dalvikvm(1867): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 42K, 4% free 2901K/3008K, paused 151ms, total 152ms
09-02 10:29:16.635: I/dalvikvm-heap(1867): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.500MB for 635808-byte allocation
09-02 10:29:16.755: D/dalvikvm(1867): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 4% free 3520K/3632K, paused 117ms, total 117ms
09-02 10:29:17.495: D/AndroidRuntime(1867): Shutting down VM
09-02 10:29:17.535: W/dalvikvm(1867): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2d74b20)
09-02 10:29:17.675: E/AndroidRuntime(1867): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-02 10:29:17.675: E/AndroidRuntime(1867): Process: com.androidrecipes.usermotionactivity, PID: 1867
09-02 10:29:17.675: E/AndroidRuntime(1867): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.androidrecipes.usermotionactivity/com.androidrecipes.usermotionactivity.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: A required meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not exist.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
09-02 10:29:17.675: E/AndroidRuntime(1867):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
09-02 10:29:17.675: E/AndroidRuntime(1867):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
09-02 10:29:17.675: E/AndroidRuntime(1867):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
09-02 10:29:17.675: E/AndroidRuntime(1867):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
09-02 10:29:17.675: E/AndroidRuntime(1867):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-02 10:29:17.675: E/AndroidRuntime(1867):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
09-02 10:29:17.675: E/AndroidRuntime(1867):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
09-02 10:29:17.675: E/AndroidRuntime(1867):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-02 10:29:17.675: E/AndroidRuntime(1867):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-02 10:29:17.675: E/AndroidRuntime(1867):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
09-02 10:29:17.675: E/AndroidRuntime(1867):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
09-02 10:29:17.675: E/AndroidRuntime(1867):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-02 10:29:17.675: E/AndroidRuntime(1867): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: A required meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not exist.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
09-02 10:29:17.675: E/AndroidRuntime(1867):     at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.A(Unknown Source)
09-02 10:29:17.675: E/AndroidRuntime(1867):     at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
09-02 10:29:17.675: E/AndroidRuntime(1867):     at com.androidrecipes.usermotionactivity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:69)
09-02 10:29:17.675: E/AndroidRuntime(1867):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
09-02 10:29:17.675: E/AndroidRuntime(1867):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
09-02 10:29:17.675: E/AndroidRuntime(1867):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
09-02 10:29:17.675: E/AndroidRuntime(1867):     ... 11 more
```

I have included the necssary permission and there are no errors in the code.
However it says "Unfortunately, UserMotion has stopped".
Please help.

Comment: did you even read the error?

Comment: I am kind of new to this.Could you help!

Comment: @SagarNarang new or not if you can read you can fix your problem because the error tells you what to do

Comment: @tyczi said, he is new, we should teach him(@SagarNarang), he dont know where he can find his mistake in logcat.

Comment: @SagarNarang here is the error showing your logcat
 09-02 10:29:17.675: E/AndroidRuntime(1867): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: A required meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not exist.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

Comment: @naveedahmad thanks! recitfied it.

Comment: if your problem is solved kindly accept the answer that others could find their solutions easily

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to this missing tag inside  tagin manifest

```
<application>
....
....
<meta-data  
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</appliacation
```